# Built a text slider with jQuery but needs some improvement

Tags: jquery, slider

I built a small slider with jQuery a few months ago, and I'm recycling it to use in a new project. Originally, it was sliding images, but I need it to slide text. Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var About = {
    init: function () {
        var text_spans = $('.headline-box span'),
            extracts = new Array(),
            delay = 5,
            current = 0;

        text_spans.each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                current = index;
            }
            extracts.push($(this));
        });

        var interval = setInterval(function () {

            target = (current < (extracts.length - 1)) ? current + 1 : 0;

            extracts[current].slideUp('slow');
            extracts[target].slideDown('slow');

            current = target;

        }, delay * 500);

    }
}

About.init();

});
```

However, right now it doesn't work very well. For example:

- When it gets to the end of the loop of `span`'s, it takes a delay (that is built into the code) instead of automatically cycling round to the first `span` again.
- I have two instances of the same slider on my page, using the same classname etc. However, it only executes one at a time (i.e one executes in a loop, and then the other will start).
- Sometimes the `span`'s will have `display: block;` as inline CSS instead of `display: inline;`. Usually it only happens to the first one in the loop.

To give you a bit of context, it's supposed to be used as a news-ticker type thing which is automated. At the moment I have 3 `span`'s in the loop but I need to be able to add more.

Sorry if this sounds like a list of demands, but I've been going through it for a while now with no luck.

Thank you to anyone who can help :)

Comment: As a sidenote, did you look at the `<marquee>` tag ?

Comment: @adeneo good suggestion, but doesn't work quite as I need it to: I want each <code>span</code> (I have 3 in a loop right now) to be cycled through, one-by-one. The marquee element only slides the text across the page (unless you have another way to use it). Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: why don't you make a small demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/PBKh7/
Annoyingly, it doesn't really display the problems as well, because it's not in the context of my web page. However, it does have one problem: the slideDown()/slideUp() method from jQuery has a default of display: block;, set with inline CSS. Anyone know how to change to display: inline;?

Comment: @adeneo AFAEK marqee is deprecated

Comment: @roXon - Yeah, it's replaced with marqee styles in CSS3, and I think only webkit supports those, but the old deprecated tag still works in all browsers, and this functionalty is for some reason coming back, unfortunately, soon we'll be having blink tags aswell ?